Effect of Basis Change on Absolute Vector Magnitudes
Does Basis Change Affect the Absolute Magnitude of Vectors?
How does a change in basis impact the absolute length of vectors?
I'm trying to understand the effect of a basis change on the absolute magnitude (or length) of vectors. Specifically, I'm wondering if the absolute magnitude of a vector changes when we change the basis.
For instance, let's say we have a vector v in basis B and its magnitude is represented as $$||v||_B$$. If we change the basis to C, would the magnitude of the vector change? In other words, is it possible for $$||v||_B ≠ ||v||_C$$?
I'm interested in understanding this in the context where B and C span the same vector space. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Ask your favorite search engine for "equivalence of norms".

Btw, what is your definition of "$||v||_B$"? (Please put in in your post rather than in a comment)

Also, Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.

Please, can you write all of your comments in a single comment?

I wrote them separately on purpose, because they deal with distinct points.
